# Is the exchange-correlation term in Kohn-Sham equation always positive or negative?

Tags: density-functional-theory

The potential terms of the Hamiltonian in the Kohn-Sham equation are the external, Hartree, and exchange-correlation terms, which can be written as:

$V_{ext}(r) = - \sum_{i=1}^{M} \frac{Z_i} {||r - R_i||} \\
V_{H}(r) = \int \frac {\rho(r')} {||r - r'||} dr' \\
V_{xc}(r) = \int f(\rho(r)) dr$

The external potential is always negative because it contains the atomic number but has minus sign; the Hartree is always positive because the density $\rho$ is always positive.

Here, $V_{xc}$ can be written using a function $f$ by various approximation approaches (e.g., LDA), but is this $V_{xc}$ term always positive? Or can this $V_{xc}$ be negative depending on the type of approximation?

Comment: I think that $V_{ext}$ is not the external potential, it is the Coulomb potential between electrons and nuclei. The external potential, as the name, is a potential where your system can be, for example, an electric field.

Comment: In the 29 page of this slide (http://physics.gu.se/~tfkhj/lecture_VIII_DFT-3.pdf), the $v_{ext}$ is defined as I described. This equation is not correct?

Comment: The choose of *external* as a label, looks for me as an unhappy choice. Following the description of the term in the slide, $V_{ext}$ is the *potential from the nuclei*. Of course is *external* to electrons, but the nuclei are part of the system!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is true at least for the exchange energy $$
E = \int \epsilon_{x}({\bf r}) {\rm d}^3r
$$
which is usually written in terms of an enhancement function $F$ times the local density approximation's exchange energy (which is always negative)
$$
 \epsilon_{x}({\bf r}) = - C n^{4/3}({\bf r}) F(\gamma, \tau) {\rm d}^3r
$$
where $\gamma$ is the reduced gradient and $\tau$ is the local kinetic energy density. If the enhancement function is nonnegative, $\epsilon_x$ will also be nonnegative.

The correlation energy is a correction to the mean field, and it is much smaller than the exchange energy, thus on this argument alone it should be always negative. However, I would expect the correlation energy to also be always negative, because that is basically the definition of correlation energy: it's the energy gain you get by switching from Hartree-Fock to a many-electron description like MP2, CCSD or FCI.

Comment: No, Pauli repulsion is already included in the Kohn-Sham determinant, the same way it is also included in Hartree-Fock. You need to worry about the Pauli potential only in orbital-free density functional theory.